# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

i am implementing **pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift**'

but in **SocketEngine.swift** file i'm getting this error.

```
 private func handleBase64(message: String) {
            // binary in base64 string
            let noPrefix = message[message.index(message.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)..<message.endIndex]

            if let data = Data(base64Encoded: noPrefix, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                client?.parseEngineBinaryData(data)
            }
        }
```

[image]

thanks in advance!!

Comment: `String(noPrefix)`

Comment: can you explain meaning of this error??? @LeoDabus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`noPrefix` is of type `Substring`, just coerce it to String:

```
if let data: Data = Data(base64Encoded: String(noPrefix), options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
    ...
}
```