# Why can't swift convert double to string?

Tags: swift

why is this line

```
 first = Double(label.text)!
```

giving this error

Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Please provide more context in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type of expression is ambiguous without more context swift 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316321/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-swift-4-0)

Comment: The title says "convert double to string" but the code in the question seems like you're trying to convert a string to a double. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

`label.text` is optional. Use this instead :

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "12"

guard let text = label.text else {
    fatalError("No text")
}

guard let first = Double(text) else {
    fatalError("The text isn't a double")
}

print(first) //12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do it simply

```
let text = label.text ?? "3.0"

let first = Double(text)

print(first)
```